# Using Google Apps Script to get responses from multiple forms and send an email once to each respondent

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been puzzling this over for some time and have searched extensively, but found no solution.

I'm using Google Apps Script and I run events for a large organization and we have about 80 different registration Google Forms for these events. I want to get the registrant's email address and send them an email when they submit their form. This is easy to accomplish by setting up each individual form. Ideally, I would set up the onSubmit trigger for the form and then copy that form for each new event. However, it seems you cannot install a trigger programmatically without going to the form and running the script manually, and then authorize it. When a form is copied it also loses all its triggers. Am I wrong about this? Doing this for each form is not realistic given that events are added all the time and I have other responsibilities.

**Is there no way to set a trigger for these files without running and authorizing each one?**

**My other solution is:**
I am trying to get all the forms in a folder and then get the responses and send a single email to each registrant. This seems overly complicated and requires checking all the forms regularly since there are no triggers for the individual forms. I tried setting triggers in my spreadsheet for the forms and this works, but the number of triggers for a spreadsheet is limited to 20, so doesn't work here. Running my script every minute and then checking if an email has been sent to each respondent seems possible, but complex and possibly prone to errors...

Thanks for any help you can offer!

---

pgSystemTester's answer worked for me.
I added two bits of code.

One, to declare the time stamp value to zero if there wasn't one
there.

Two, the code needed a "-1" when you get dRange or you insert a new
row which each run.

```
function sendEmailsCalendarInvite() {
  const dRange = sheet.getRange(2, registrationFormIdId, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
    var theList = dRange.getValues();
    for (i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
      if (theList [i][1] == ''){
        theList[i][1] = 0;
      }
      if (theList[i][0] != '') {
        var aForm = FormApp.openById(theList[i][0]);
        var latestReply = theList[i][1];
        var allResponses = aForm.getResponses();
        
        for (var r = 0; r < allResponses.length; r++) {
          var aResponse = allResponses[r];
          var rTime = aResponse.getTimestamp();
          if (rTime > theList[i][1]) {
            //run procedure on response using aForm and aResponse variables
            console.log('If ran')
            if (rTime > latestReply) {
              //updates latest timestamp if needed
              latestReply = rTime;
            }
            //next reply
          }
        }
        theList[i][1] = latestReply;
        //next form
      }
    }
    //updates timestamps
    dRange.setValues(theList);
  }
```

Comment: Are these Google Form?

Comment: Yes, this is all Google Forms.

Comment: Are all of the forms linked to separate spreadsheets?

Comment: They are currently linked to nothing. I could create spreadsheets and set the destination to spreadsheets. I know how to do that, but it seems the trigger issue is the same.

Comment: Hey @Cooper, I was just joking. You're right of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a simple solution that will work. Setup a spreadsheet that holds all Form ID's you wish to check and then a corresponding latest response. Then set this below trigger to run every ten minutes or so.

[image]

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const dRange = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(),2 );

function loopFormsOnSheet() {
  var theList = dRange.getValues();

  for(i=0;i<theList.length;i++){
    if(theList[i][0]!=''){
   var aForm = FormApp.openById(theList[i][0]);
   var latestReply = theList[i][1];
   var allResponses = aForm.getResponses();
    for(var r=0;r<allResponses.length;r++){
      var aResponse = allResponses[r];
      var rTime = aResponse.getTimestamp();
      if(rTime > theList[i][1]){
        //run procedure on response using aForm and aResponse variables
        
        if(rTime >latestReply){
          //updates latest timestamp if needed
          latestReply=rTime;
        }
        //next reply
      }
    }
    theList[i][1] = latestReply;
    //next form
    }
  }
  //updates timestamps
  dRange.setValues(theList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I had to add one declaration (is that the right word?). if (theList [i][1] == ''){
        theList[i][1] = 0;
      }

Comment: Yep. Nice job. You're on your way.  Thx. For accepting.